# Get index of checked radio button in group

Tags: c++, qt, radio-button

I have several radio buttons in a group, is there a way to get the index of the currently checked item?

Right now I use this code:

```
int getCheckedRadioButton(QWidget *w)
{
    int ii = 0;
    foreach (QRadioButton *button, w->findChildren<QRadioButton*>()) {
        if (button->isChecked()) {
            return ii;
        }
        ii++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This works well enough, but maybe there is a standard Qt function or way to do it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's a use case for [`QButtonGroup`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html).

Group your radio buttons with `QButtonGroup` if you haven't already. For each button, use [`QButtonGroup::addButton(button, id)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html#addButton-2) to assign consecutive ids to your buttons, starting with zero.

Then, to receive the index of the button, use [`QButtonGroup::checkedId()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html#checkedId).

When you use the Qt designer to design your form, you can group buttons by selecting them and choosing "Assign to button group" > "New button group" from the context menu. But I think you cannot manually assign IDs to the buttons in the group. Instead, use [`QButtonGroup::setId(button, id)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html#setId) after `setupUI` in order to change the automatically assigned IDs. (They are kind of confusing, counting negative from -2 and I don't know how the designer chooses the order exactly, so I wouldn't recommend to depend on that order.)

Comment: Really excellent answer! The upvotes don't do it justice, so I thought I'd explicitly say thank you for writing it :)

Comment: Ditto on the excellent answer.  There is so much that is obtuse about Qt to the novice.  Your answer kept me from doing more work.